# How to make the element(resource) in the panel

Tags: c#, winforms

This code of my button:

```
        int offsetY = 5;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int index = 1;            

        //Start adds new panel and new label
        Panel b = new Panel();
        Label la = new Label();

        //Adds panel properties
        b.Controls.Add(la);
        b.Location = new Point(x, y + offsetY);
        b.Size = new Size(633, 119);
        newhaven.Class1 cl = new newhaven.Class1();
        b.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
        b.ResumeLayout(false);


        //Adds label properties
        x = 0;
        y = -20;
        la.Location = new Point(x,y);
       // la.Size = new Size(60, 30);
        la.Text = "Hello";
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(la);
```

I want to hello to be in the panel)

[image]

Are can you help me?

Comment: Are you sure that's WPF? :)

Comment: Sorry( i miss. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right, but need to take care of the position co-ordinates for the label, please ensure that they lie inside the panel co-ordinates.

The following works:

```
            int offsetY = 5;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int index = 1;

            //Start adds new panel and new label
            Panel b = new Panel();
            Label la = new Label();

            //Adds panel properties
            b.Controls.Add(la);
            b.Location = new Point(x, y + offsetY);
            b.Size = new Size(633, 119);
            //newhaven.Class1 cl = new newhaven.Class1();
            b.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
            b.ResumeLayout(false);


            // Adds label properties -
            // commented the co-ordinates and using the same as that of panel
            //x = 0;
            //y = -20;
            la.Location = new Point(x, y + offsetY);
            // la.Size = new Size(60, 30);
            la.Text = "Hello";

            // no need to add the label separately, its inside the panel
            //flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(la);
```